# getline doesn't work after fflush

Tags: c++, xcode, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int num;
    string str;

    cout << "Input an integer a= ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    cout << "Input a string str= ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin,str);
    cout << str << endl;
    cout << "End program" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Input an integer a= 1
1
Input a string str= 
End program
```

The `getline` after fflush() does not work.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it's not exactly a getline() problem.  If you do not read `num` first, getline() is OK.

Comment: Try using `getchar();` instead of `fflush(stdin);`

Comment: No idea why this question ended up in a review queue, but I made some fixes to take it out of there.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, since the behavior of fflush() is only defined for output streams. Furthermore, this is a "C style" function and shouldn't be combined with C++ console I/O.

Instead of fflush(), you can discard the new line character by adding `cin.get()` directly after your previous cin call:

```
cin >> num;
cin.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

When the program prompts you "the Input an integer a= ", you type 1 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so after `cin >> num;`, an newline remains in the stream. Then the new line will be assigned to `str`. That's why you think the `getline` after `fflush` (As Lundin's answer says, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior)does not work.

Use `cin.ignore(A_BIG_NUM, '\n');` before `getline` to ignore the new line.